# Hibernate criteria of Projection

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 classes with a relation `@OneToOne`: `User` and `Player`.

User contain a player:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Column(name = "nickname")
    private String nickname;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_player")
    private Player player;

   //getters and setters...
}
```

I want to query user with only `nickname` and `player`, and with `player` I don't want all attributes, I only want 2.

This is what I have now:

```
    //Projections for the class User
    ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("id"), "id");
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("nickname"), "nickname");
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("player"), "player");

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
    criteria.setFirstResult(player.getPvpRank() - 5);
    criteria.setMaxResults(11);
    criteria.createAlias("player", "p");
    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("p.pvpRank"));
    criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
    criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(User.class));
```

I am getting only `nickname`, `id` and the `player`, but how can I set projections to the player to only get `player.level` and not all the attributes?

Comment: Check the detailed solution here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/29756903/4560215

Answer (score 0):

Its think it is exactly as you suggest:

```
projectionList.add(Projections.property("player.level"), "player.level");
```

Comment: Im getting:
`could not resolve property: player.level of: model.User`

Answer (score 0):

*First create alias* for the JoinColumn table `Player` in `User` & *then refer it in your projectionList*.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
criteria.createAlias("player", "p");
projectionList.add(Projections.property("p.level"), "player");
...
criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(User.class));
```

I hope this helps you.